# MVC3/C#/Razor/EF handling data from multiple partial 'create views'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-4.1

For registering a new customer I have several partials on my view which refer to corresponding tables in my database.
Primary keys are identity fields, that's why no IDs on the view. To insert a new customer I need to insert 3 occurrences of address(visiting, postal and contact person's), then insert a row for contract, contact_person(with using addressId from one of already inserted addresses) and finally proceed with inserting a new customer which will contain foreign keys referencing to just inserted visiting and postal addresses, contract and contact person.

Could you recommend the best/easiest way to pass the data from these partial views as objects to CustomerController and handle the objects there please? 
Links to examples of handling similar situations will be also highly appreciated.

Image of my page:
http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p673/swell_daze/customer_registration_zps563341d0.png

Image of tables:
http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p673/swell_daze/tables_zpsc60b644a.png

View code:

```
@model CIM.Models.customer

<h2>Register new customer</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>New customer registration</legend>
    <fieldset class="span3">
    <legend>Basic information</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, "Name")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.groupId, "Customer group")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("groupId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.groupId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.status, "Status")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("status")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="span3">
        <legend>Visiting address</legend>
        <div>
            @{
Html.RenderPartial("AddressPartial");
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="width:270px">
        <legend>Postal address</legend>
        <div>
            @{
Html.RenderPartial("AddressPartial");
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="span3">
    <legend>Contract</legend>
    <div>
    @{
Html.RenderPartial("ContractPartial");
        }
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="span3" style="width:540px">
    <legend>Contact person</legend>
    <div>
    @{
Html.RenderPartial("ContactPersonPartial");
        }
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" style="margin-right:1em"/>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Customer", new {@class="btn btn-danger", @type="button"})
    </p>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

}

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the problem, but couldn't you use hidden fields to differentiate the three addresses?

Comment: What I want is to pass data from the view containing several partial views as objects to controller, not fields since there will be about 20 parameters in my Create method in controller in that case. The situation is clearly seen on the image http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p673/swell_daze/customer_registration_zps563341d0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap your view data in a viewmodel, then when you submit your data it will be mapped to your viewmodel, something like this:

Create a viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string someprop1 { get; set; }
    public string someprop2 { get; set; }

    public MyAddress visitingaddress { get; set; }
    public MyAddress postaladdress { get; set; }
    public MyContactAddress contactaddress { get; set; }
}

public class MyAddress
{
    public string town { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string housenumber { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
}

public class MyContactAddress : MyAddress
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phonenumber { get; set; }
}
```

Create your view just like you have done but by using your viewmodel instead of the model you are using now (CIM.Models.customer), and then in your partials, for example in the postal address partial view do something like this:

```
.......
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.postaladdress.town)
......
```

Create your controller actions by using your viewmodel:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        //doing something here....

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        //save your data, here your viewmodel will be correctly filled
        return View(vm);
    }
```

hope this helps